# Fastest way to get all different colors on frame?

Tags: c++, opengl

We render a world with no shadows/lights/transparancy/etc - pure colored verteces. we have a panoramic fisheye camera looking at 360*360 degrees. And we have a resolution about 200*200 RGB pixels. We want to get all unique colors on given frame. What would be the fastest way to do it in OpenGL?

Comment: Say we had a frame with red triangle and a blue backgrownd in it, we wat to get a vector of 2 elements - red and blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`GL_EXT_histogram`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/histogram.txt), it might be what you are looking for:

> This extension defines pixel operations that count occurences of
>       specific color component values (histogram) and that track the minimum
>       and maximum color component values (minmax).  An optional mode allows
>       pixel data to be discarded after the histogram and/or minmax operations
>       are completed.  Otherwise the pixel data continue on to the next
>       operation unaffected.